# How I can Change The Background Colour of file_dialog in dearpygui

Tags: python, dearpygui

I am using dearpygui for a project. However, I think the File Dialog box does not look nice. I would like to change its colour to white background. Does anyone have any idea about how. I tried the following styling but did not work:

```
#dpg.toggle_viewport_fullscreen()
with dpg.theme() as global_theme:

    with dpg.theme_component(dpg.mvAll):
        dpg.add_theme_color(dpg.mvThemeCol_WindowBg, (255, 255, 255))
        dpg.add_theme_color(dpg.mvThemeCol_PopupBg, (255, 255, 255))
        dpg.add_theme_color(dpg.mvThemeCol_ModalWindowDimBg, (255, 255, 255))
        dpg.add_theme_color(dpg.mvThemeCol_FrameBg, (255, 255, 255))
        dpg.add_theme_color(dpg.mvThemeCol_FrameBg, (255, 255, 255))
        
dpg.bind_theme(global_theme)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can search in th style editor : dpg.show_style_editor() and an object dpg.mvFileDialog exists, maybe for the theme_component. [Link to documentation](https://dearpygui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/documentation/themes.html?highlight=plot#core-colors)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).